# How to prevent Tmux from scrolling off visually in multiple panes when using termite?

Tags: scroll, tmux, pane

When I open a vim buffer in tmux and then I split to two panes (in tmux) all scrolling happens in both panes. Vim gets scrolled off the screen. But the scrolling happens only visually. The vim buffer is still untouched and as soon as I go back to the vim buffer and mak a change every character I change or move appears. This happens only in termite.

Here's an image for clarification: (left side termite, right side urxvt as a comparison)

[image: Half scrolled left pane in termite. Not scrolled in urxvt]

Note that any kind of scrolling achieves this. In the above example I have scrolled on the right side by scrolling through a man page. But when using tmux's built in scrollback feature the same effect appears. Also it doesn't need to be vim on the left. Anything will be scrolled.

**So the Question:**
How to prevent Tmux from scrolling off visually in multiple panes when using termite?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the bugs/missing support in VTE for `indn` which was fixed a few years ago now.

You can try the following:

1) See if you can upgrade termite and VTE to newer versions.

2) Put `set -as terminal-overrides ',*:indn@'` in .tmux.conf and restart tmux entirely (`tmux kill-server`).

Comment: I assume VTE stands for virtual terminal emulator. Unfortunately I already run the newest version. I tried your second suggestion but it didn't change anything (I killed the server and started a new one)

Comment: What do you have `TERM` set to outside tmux?

Comment: If I launch termite, the $TERM yields 'xterm-termite'. However I launch tmux by specifying TERM:  `TERM=xterm-256color tmux new -A -s Masterarbeit`

Comment: The other thing this seems like it may be is the terminal telling tmux it supports margins when actually it doesn't. What does `printf '\033[c';cat` show?

Comment: The output is `^[[?1;2c` but it doesn't return to a shell prompt. instead I have to cancel the command to continue.

Comment: Yes that's fine, strange. That is what it prints outside tmux, right? What if you add `set -as terminal-overrides ',*:XT@'` to .tmux.conf and restart tmux completely (`tmux kill-server`)?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood. The above was in tmux. Outside tmux (simply in termite) it yields `^[[?65;1;9c` Also adding the option to tmux doesn't help either.

Comment: Hmm tmux should not use margins with 65, although it is silly of them to send it since I doubt they are fully compatible with VT520. I don't think we can debug this any further here, can you build tmux from Git master and see if the problem still occurs? If so, please open an issue at https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/new.

Comment: I am amazed. Building tmux from source has fixed the problem (I don't even have to use any of the options above in my tmux.conf). Thank you so much!

Comment: This problem rings a bell so I suspect it is something that was worked around already, although I can't spot exactly where or when.